# Cannot assign local value to global value

Tags: java, android

I am just a beginner in java/android. I was trying to pass location latitude and longitude to firebase. So I toast the message to see the value it was showing 0.0. I passed lat and long value from client.getlastlocation to the global value of lat and lon, but it is showing default value 0.0, why is this happening?

```
public class shopaction extends Fragment implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
Location location;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
FusedLocationProviderClient client;
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
String s;
Switch action;
public double lat,lon;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public shopaction() {
}
public static shopaction newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    shopaction fragment = new shopaction();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopaction, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    action = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.action);
    action.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
    Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);

            }
            client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    lat=location.getLatitude();
                    lon=location.getLongitude();
                }
            });


        }
    });
    client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            lat=location.getLatitude();
            lon=location.getLongitude();
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),lat+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    FirebaseDatabase  firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    databaseReference.child("shop").child("location").setValue(lat);
}
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(action.isChecked())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your shop is open",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        action.setText("open");
        s="open";
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your shop is closed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        action.setText("close");
        s="close";
    }

}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Comment: Before using `location.getLatitude();`, where are you assigning value to location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `getLastLocation()` returns a `Task` which then operates asynchronously. The location data are not available until the success listener call-back has actually been called. Meanwhile, your code proceeds to display a `Toast` using the current (default) values of 0 for `lat` and `lon`.

One way to fix this is to have your success listener callback display the toast, rather than your main code. So instead of this:

```
client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
        lat=location.getLatitude();
        lon=location.getLongitude();
    }
});
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),lat+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// Firebase update code that depends on location data
```

use this:

```
client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
        lat=location.getLatitude();
        lon=location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),lat+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Firebase update code that depends on location data
    }
});
```

Comment: This is showing the correct lattitude and longitude but why it is not passing to global variable

Comment: @Akishere - It is. It's just doing it asynchronously. This is one of the difficulties of using asynchronous facilities like Android's location services: you have to organize your code so that certain parts of it don't run until the data on which they depend are available. So for your case, you would want to move all the Firebase update code into the success listener, in the same way that I did with the `Toast`. (Or move it all into a separate method that is called from within the success listener.)